# Setting one-to-many relationship Core Data and Magical Record

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord

If I have a `Conversation` entity with a one-to-many relationship to `Messages` (i.e. one conversation can have many messages) and I create a new message entity like so:

```
_message = [Message MR_createInContext:_managedObjectContext];
_message set properties ...

// Use this method to set relationship?
[_conversation addToMessageObject:(Message *)]
```

If I already have a _conversation object, how do I add this new message to the conversation (in other words, how do I establish the relationship)?

Comment: You already have the method in your question. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a problem with this too, you need to create the relationship on the `_message` instead:

```
_message.conversation = _conversation;
```