# Setting one-to-many relationship with core data/magical record

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord

If I have a Conversation entity that can have many messages (another entity), do I set the relationship on the conversation or message or both?

Comment: Repost of [Setting one-to-many relationship Core Data and Magical Record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274428/setting-one-to-many-relationship-core-data-and-magical-record) Please don't do that. Edit your earlier question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set relationship on Conversation entity, it will automatically create relationship on the other entity. You need to make sure to name them properly as you might want to know what Conversation a Message belongs to and what Messages a Conversation has.